# Form is not rendering in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've been making a simple decimal to binary/octal/hex converter using a form in Visual Studio 2019, but something strange is happening.

I've created a form in `Form1.cs[Design]` by just dragging and dropping a couple of text fields , 3 buttons and a couple of labels. It looked fine. Then I clicked on the button and went to `Form1.cs` to added some programming-logic .  When I clicked back to `Form1.cs [Design]` this is what I saw:

[image]

No buttons or textfields visible. If I try to drag and drop a button again this is what I get:
[image]

So the buttons I added are there, they're just not rendering?
When I try to Ctrl+F5, there are no errors, it builds but the form looks blank as well.

Here's the code from `Form1.cs` ,

```
using System; using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DecimalConverter {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long number = long.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string Base = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
            textBox2.Text = Base;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long number = long.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string Base = Convert.ToString(number, 8);
            textBox2.Text = Base;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long number = long.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string Base = Convert.ToString(number, 16);
            textBox2.Text = Base;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    } }
```

The only non-autogenerated code is the one attached to the buttons.

The Form1_Load method is auto-generated and I think the problem is in it? I don't completely understand its function though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this .net core 3.x or full .net framework project?

Comment: Hey, I've just picked a "Windows Forms App (.Net Core)" while creating a project. I lterally wanted just a simple WinForm. Not a whole project, no. And I'm using the latest .Net Core version so it's 3.1.302 I believe.

Comment: Something went wrong with the Form1.Designer.cs file, we can't see it.  We can see the tab for it, and that it got changed, do make sure to never edit this file yourself.  .NETCore designer support is still work-in-progress so picking the (.NET Framework) project template is recommended.

Comment: Do you know the difference between "Windows Forms App (.Net Framework)" and the one you have? And you are *sure* you want "core", right?

Comment: @Hans Passant, hey. I did not edit Form1.Designer.cs myself. I think it got edited automatically when I added some functionality to the buttons. I've uploaded the project to github you can check it out here https://github.com/sasharkv/DecimalConverter.

Comment: @Sinatr, I know that Core is the newer follow up to .Net Framework and that there are some differences. However, I'm not sure if it's important if I'm literally just trying to make a simple WinForm decimal converter?

Comment: I don't think you're focusing enough on the rest of @HansPassant comment: `Something went wrong with the Form1.Designer.cs file ... .NETCore designer support is still work-in-progress so picking the (.NET Framework) project template is recommended`

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I read it, I'm just surpised something so basic cant be done in .Net Core? (It probably can but I'm missing something.) . I'm going to re-make it in .Net Framework then. (And thanks for the edits. Highly appreciated.)

Comment: The WinForms designer support for [.net core 3.1 based projects is still in preview state](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/) and some features are missing. With .net 5, Microsoft hopes to release the [designer with all features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs-roadmap#net)

Comment: @magicandre1981Thank you for the info!

Comment: @magicandre1981, based on my test, it works well. Therefore, I have two suggestions. First, I recommend that you use the latest vs2019 version. Second, I suggest that you can check if designer file has problems. Third, It is best for you to use .net framework winform because .net core  winform is in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Some controls have a same names. Check it